# My JSON contains "false" as a value for a key which should be "False" (boolean). How to change this?

Tags: python, json

```
ap = {  
   "api_version":"3.1",
   "metadata":{  
      "total_matches":1,
      "kind":"vm",
      "length":1,
      "offset":true
   }
```

Above JSON contains `false` and `true` as values in between which should be `True` and `False` as those are boolean. How to fix this in python?

Comment: JavaScript uses `true` and `false`, so that's *correct* for JSON.

Comment: JSON is not valid Python. Use `json.loads` to transform JSON into Python values.

Comment: @FlorianH but `bool('false')` might be surprising.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right it is !

Comment: @FlorianH any non-empty string evaluates truthy, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not valid JSON. Nor is it a valid Python dictionary.

When working with JSON, use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module, which will convert the `true` to Python boolean value `True`:

```
>>> jsontext="""{  
   "api_version":"3.1",
   "metadata":{  
      "total_matches":1,
      "kind":"vm",
      "length":1,
      "offset":true}
   }"""

>>> json.loads(jsontext)

{'api_version': '3.1', 'metadata': {'total_matches': 1, 'kind': 'vm', 'length': 1, 'offset': True}}
```